# Evaluating payload provided when calling invoke endpoint operation

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker

I'm working on a credit fraud dataset on sagemaker. I'm using a linear learner binary classification algorithm. I divided the data into training and test sets and got the results for test set. When I tried to evaluate model performance characteristics on training set, I'm getting the following error

```
 An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error 
(400) from model with message "unable to evaluate payload provided".
```

I mentioned the code below

```
train_data = 's3://{}/{}/{}'.format(bucket, prefix, 'train/examples') #making train_data

#making test_data
test_key = "{}/test/examples".format(prefix)
s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(test_key, 'test_data')

#preparing train channels for training the data
train_channel = sagemaker.session.s3_input(train_data, content_type='text/csv')

#training the data
linear.fit(inputs=train_channel,  logs=True)

#creating the endpoint
linear_predictor = linear.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                             instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')

#getting the results on test_data
l = []
with open('test_data', 'r') as f:
for j in range(0,56962):
    single_test = f.readline()
    result = linear_predictor.predict(single_test)
    l.append(result)
    if j%10000 ==0 :
        print(j)
print(l[0:10])

#getting the results on train_data
#THE CODE BELOW IS THROWING THE ABOVE MENTIONED ERROR
q =[]
with open('train_data', 'r') as f:
for j in range(0,56962):
    single_test = f.readline()
    result = linear_predictor.predict(single_test)
    q.append(result)
    if j%10000 ==0 :
        print(j)
print(q[0:10])
```

I'm getting the results on test data. I stored it in list l. For getting the results on the training set, I followed the similar procedure, but I'm getting the above mentioned error. Can someone please offer a resolution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"unable to evaluate payload provided" occurs only when the input data format is not compatible with the ML model you created. In this case, to get results on training set, we need to remove the last column(label column) before passing it to endpoint